# Can you declare a pointer on the heap?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, heap-memory

This is the method for creating a variable on the heap in C++:

```
T *ptr = new T;
```

ptr refers to a pointer to the new T, obviously. My question is, can you do this:

```
T *ptr = new T*;
```

That seems like it could lead to some very, very dangerous code. Does anyone know if this is possible/how to use it properly?

Comment: C++ is very consistent in every *sub-language in it* :)

Comment: While you already got answers showing you the syntax, so far nobody asked you why you need this. It surely seems suspicious to me.

Comment: I just thought it was interesting. I had never considered it. I do not have a need for it (besides, perhaps, optimizing rarely used routines for memory consumption).

Comment: One of the key things to realize about pointers is that there is absolutely *nothing* special about them. They are types that can be allocated just like any other type. They can exist on the heap, on the stack, as static variables or anything else you can do with any other type. You can create pointers or references to them. They are just types.

Comment: For reference: creating a pointer on the heap does not reduce memory consumption, it increases it. While your pointer to the int can be created on the heap, you have to create a pointer to the pointer on the stack.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
int** ppint = new int*;
*ppint = new int;

delete *ppint;
delete ppint;
```

Answer (score 7):

`new T*` returns a pointer to a pointer to a T. So the declaration is not correct, it should be:

```
T** ptr = new T*;
```

And it will reside on the heap.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can declare a pointer to a pointer... and yes, the pointer will be on the heap.

Answer (score 4):

It was mentioned as why you might need something like this. The thing that comes to mind is a dynamic array. (Most vector implementations use this actually.)

```
// Create array of pointers to object
int start = 10;
SomeObject** dynamic = new SomeObject*[start];
// stuff happens and it gets filled
// we need it to be bigger
{
    SomeObject** tmp = new SomeObject*[start * 2];
    for (size_t x = 0; x < start; ++x)
        tmp[x] = dynamic[x];
    delete [] dynamic;
    dynamic = tmp;
}
// now our dynamic array is twice the size
```

As a result, we copy a bunch of pointers to increase our array, not the objects themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do

```
T *ptr = new T*;
```

since the return type of `new foo` is "pointer to foo" or `foo *`.

You can do

```
T **ptr = new T*;
```